# How many simultaneous websocket connections are allowed per domain in Safari on IOS?

Tags: ios, safari, websocket, signalr

We are experiencing problems with Safari on IOS devices when opening multiple web pages simultaneously to our site.

It seems that the problems are related to our long-polling requests and the limit Safari has on concurrent connections per domain.

Will this be resolved if we switch to websockets in SignalR or will the Safari imposed limits on the number of concurrent connections per domain still be a problem for us?

Comment: did you speak about iOS programming or using safari on iOS?

Comment: No, this is not directly related to iOS programming. My questions is if the limit which exists for Safari for webserver connectiona also applies to Websockets.

Comment: then you should connect to apples support sites and communities or use other stackexchange forum. this one is only programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Safari and Websockets - in the new version of SignalR you can make connections to multiple hubs so this increases the number of overall connections that count towards the limit.

I'm seeing blocking if I have more than a couple connections. Still trying to figure it out but for sure safari is still enforcing a limit even in 2019 :-(

I'm seeing it block COMPLETELY if I have **more than 3 connections.**

Even the blue bar is stuck.

I can't even make a Web API call.

If I stop a connection on the server side (closing my angular dev server) then it unblocks (back down to 3 connections).

Comment: turns out the self signed root certificate I used needs installing in iOS to be trusted and to allow websockets - even though https is ok. I had to recreate my CA cert with the 'extension' `Subject Type=CA` to get iOS to support it properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771022/how-to-create-and-install-x-509-self-signed-certificates-in-windows-10-without-u